# display images in <img> tag using nsdata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

is this possible? my app will download a zip file from the server and I save all the images in an array like this:

```
    ZipReadStream *read = [unzipFile readCurrentFileInZip];
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:info.length];
    int bytesRead= [read readDataWithBuffer:data];

    if(bytesRead > 0)
    {
     [imagesData addObject:data];
     [imagesName addObject:info.name];
    }
```

then I filter w/c images to be displayed inside the uiview and w/c images to be displayed inside the uiwebview. I display the images inside the uiview like this:

```
    UIImage *imageForThisQuestion = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[imagesData       
    objectAtIndex:indexOfThisImage]];
```

this works fine inside the uiview. but how do I display the some of the images inside the uiwebview? can I use the  tag here? and also my uiwebview might appear in this format:

```
    "blah blah blah blah <img src...> blah blah blah <img src...>"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to save an image in file to refer on it in html like < img src="myimage.png">, right? You can use [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to encode your image into URI, and use img tag like

< img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" >

Read [hear](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) how to base64 encode NSData of your image.

Comment: That's what I have in mind before I posted my question here but I was hoping to get a different approach to solve this problem :D. Anyway, I think base64 encoding an NSData is slow. Is there any other method I can use aside from encoding this to base64? I'm only new to iOS by the way. :)

Comment: @Dffy, another approach might be save image in file and refer on it in img tag by it's file name, as usual. I don't see another way.

Comment: @Diffy, don't mention it. Mark answer accepted if it replies your question and suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting a quick and clear answer and slip reading the whole article supplied above, this is the code you want to use:

```
NSString* imgInBase64 = [imageObject base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSString* imgSrcValue = [@"data:image/png;base64," stringByAppendingString:imgInBase64]
```

and you inject that string to any `<img src="{{imgSrcValue}}">` element. Notice the 0 value to the base64EncodedStringWithOptions which may help you avoid crashes with images which produce huge Base64 strings. Also you can change the png to any supported image format

Answer (score -1):

You have to load the HTML code with the correct `baseURL`:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Then, in your HTML code:

```
<img src="myimage.png">
```

Comment: How that will work if an image IS in memory only, and NOT in a file?

Comment: You're right, I've answered too fast without noticing it in the question. Correcting my answer...